# How to use Case in a VB Macros combo box?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I'm constructing a macro form, and I have this code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = Array("Tipo A", "Tipo B", "Tipo C")
End Sub
```

I want to know how to use a case from this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use a [`Select Case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx), you can simple do it like this:

```
Select Case ComboBox1
Case "Tipo A"
    ' what you want to do for Tipo A
Case "Tipo B"
    ' and another for Tipo B
Case "Tipo C"
    ' for Tipo C
Case Else
    ' what you want to do otherwise
End Select
```

You can add this in to what ever `Form Control Event` you want to use.
Take note that you can only evaluate the `ComboBox1` at runtime.